# Subscribe to Word Events

Tags: ms-word, office-js

Is there way to subscribe to word events to call office js functions, primarily to functions like cut paste undo etc. Am i missing something. I have gone thru the documentation and found some events like DocumentSelectionChangedEvent , BindingDataChangedEventArgs.

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: The range of interceptable events is limited. See: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InterceptSavePrint.htm https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/AppClassEvents.htm. Although the articles are for VBA, the API considerations for JS are the same.

Comment: No, that's pretty much it - at least at  present as far as the Office JS APIs are concerned. The COM API provides a few more, but none for the things you list. There are some alternatives for the COM APIs, such as re-purposing Ribbon commands or, for VBA, assigning commands to keyboard shortcuts and to macros.